# How do I gather JSON data nested in an array using NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have the following JSON:

```
{
0: 200,
error: false,
campaigns: {
current_campaigns: [
                {
                id: "1150",
                campaign_type_id: "1",
                campaign_type: "Type",
                title: "Name (with type) ",
                url: "http://www.example.com",
                special: null,
                campaign_instructions: "Here's what you do",
                pay_description: "",
                start: "2013-10-14 00:00:00",
                end: "2014-03-31 23:59:59"
                },
                {
                id: "1151",
                campaign_type_id: "1",
                campaign_type: "Type",
                title: "Name (with type) ",
                url: "http://www.example.com",
                special: null,
                campaign_instructions: "Here's what you do",
                pay_description: "",
                start: "2013-10-14 00:00:00",
                end: "2014-03-31 23:59:59"
                },
    ],
    new_campaigns: [
                {
                id: "1152",
                campaign_type_id: "1",
                campaign_type: "Type",
                title: "Name (with type) ",
                url: "http://www.example.com",
                special: null,
                campaign_instructions: "Here's what you do",
                pay_description: "",
                start: "2013-10-14 00:00:00",
                end: "2014-03-31 23:59:59"
                }

    ]
}
```

And the following code

```
NSURL *theJSON = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somejsonurl"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theJSON];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError){
    NSError *errorJson = nil;
NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0     error:&errorJson];

    NSArray *campaigns = dataDictionary[@"campaigns"];

    for (NSDictionary *campaignList in campaigns) {
        NSLog(@"Call gave: %@", campaigns);
    }
```

How would I end up logging the current_campaign title?
I tried

```
   NSLog(@"%@", [campaignList objectForKey:@"title"]);
   NSLog(@"%@", campaigns[@"title"] );
```

and no success. I'm fairly new at Objective C and am having trouble understanding how you dig into JSON with NSArray and NSDictionary. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It takes only 5-10 minutes.

Comment: "Go learn X" is probably the least helpful way to assist someone with a question.

Comment: **DID YOU TRY???**  It really **does** only take only 5-10 minutes to learn, and when you learn it JSON becomes far less confusing.  It's really blazingly simple when you understand it.

Comment: I agree with Hot Licks.  My tip on recognizing [] and {} will help you understand the breakdown of the two structures that make up JSON objects, but this is just the beginning.  I would also suggest learning more about it.  I think Hot Licks is just trying to help.

Comment: I think your approach is different ElJay. Helpful vs http://bit.ly/1nGQMVA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to remember about `JSON` is that every time you see a bracket "[", that means the beginning of an `Array` and "]" is the end.  Every time you see a curly brace "{" that means the beginning of a `Dictionary` and "}" is the end.

So in your example, `campaigns` is a `Dictionary` element with another `Dictionary` (`current_campaigns`) that contains an `Array` of `Dictionaries`.  Each of those `Dictionaries` has a `key` called `title`.

So the long version (untested):

```
NSDictionary *campaigns = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"campaigns"];
NSArray *currentCampaigns = [campaigns objectForKey:@"current_campaigns"];
for (NSDictionary *thisCampaign in currentCampaigns) {
    NSLog(@"title: %@", [thisCampaign objectForKey:@"title"]);
}
```

Comment: Not only did this work (syntax was missing ':' after objectForKey but nbd) like magic... your hint on [] and {} was exactly the tip I needed to do it right going forward. Thank you!

Comment: @Aubrey -- That's odd because that was the exact advice I gave you -- to go to json.org and learn the syntax.  Why was that "not helpful" when the "hint" you got above was the exact same thing??

Comment: The advice you gave was "go learn it somewhere" vs offering a solution as ElJay did above. Amazing how you have this level of cred when you troll like this.